# Why do Qt timers fire less frequently when not updating the GUI?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

Below is a simple Qt for Python (PySide6) application that tries to count the number of times a slot gets called in one second:

```py
import time
from PySide6.QtCore import *
from PySide6.QtTest import *
from PySide6.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(400, 300)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.sheep_number = 0
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.count_sheep)
        self.counted_sheep_label = QLabel()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.counted_sheep_label)  # comment out this line to see the bug

    @Slot()
    def count_sheep(self):
        self.sheep_number += 1
        self.counted_sheep_label.setText(f"Counted {self.sheep_number} sheep.")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QApplication([])
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    main_window.timer.start()
    then = time.time()
    QTest.qWait(1000)
    main_window.timer.stop()
    t = time.time() - then
    print(t, main_window.sheep_number)
```

The code brings up a GUI and leaves it on the screen for 1 second. It then prints the time that elapsed (according to Python rather than Qt) and number of calls to the slot. When I run this on my laptop, I get `1.0010387897491455` and `7155`

However, when I comment out the indicated line, I get `1.0011870861053467` `88`.

I do not understand this behavior. Why would *not* drawing the GUI cause `QTimer` to fire less often?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. In fact, as expected, the exact opposite occurs - not showing the label greatly increases the number of calls (by about one order of magnitude). This is using either qt 6.5.0 / pyside-6.5.0 or qt-5.15.9 / pyqt-5.15.9 on linux.

Comment: I'm using PySide6 (6.5) on macOS.

Comment: The default interval for QTimer is zero. According to the [Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#interval-prop), this means it will "time out as soon as all the events in the window system's event queue have been processed". This would seem to imply the interval is strictly indeterminate (i.e. not necessarily zero milliseconds). If you set a non-zero interval, presumably you should see no significant difference between showing and not showing the label (that's what I see on linux, anyway).

Comment: Do you have a concrete use-case for counting slot calls, or is that just a way to test the behaviour of QTimer?

Comment: @ekhumoro Setting the interval to something small (e.g., 1) does not fix the issue. It makes no difference at all unless the interval is greater ~12, which is what the bottlenecked rate (~80/90 per second) is on my machine.

Comment: @ekhumoro I'm polling a human interface device (HID, a bluetooth gamepad in my case) and I suspected it was polling too slowly, hence this minimal example.

Comment: Why are you using a timer to do that?

Comment: Why not? The docs suggest this a common approach "As a special case, a QTimer with a timeout of 0 will time out as soon as possible ... Zero timers can be used to do some work while still providing a snappy user interface ...  This is the traditional way of implementing heavy work in GUI applications."

Comment: @sammosummo I believe you're reading a different meaning in that. The 0 singleShot timer is not intended to make frequent calls to a function, it's intended to keep the UI responsive *while* doing heavy work. I don't know why you're using that approach to poll the HID (shouldn't there be dedicated libraries for that?) but using QTimer for that doesn't seem a correct approach, and a separate QThread with its own while loop should be used instead.

Comment: @sammosummo And that quote continues: "but as multithreading is nowadays becoming available on more and more platforms, we expect that zero-millisecond QTimer objects will gradually be replaced by QThreads". Which is what I was getting at in my question above.

Comment: There's a module for game controllers in Qt but it hasn't been ported to PySide. There's also a bluetooth module, which is part of PySide but it has all sorts of issues and I can't get even minimal examples working properly across computers. So I'm using another library to read from the HID and need some way to poll it in my app. I saw the rest of the quote, and have explored QThreads, but I don't believe there will be a large benefit in terms of responsiveness and latency in my case (because there isn't a huge amount else going on in the main loop) to warrant the added code complexity.

Comment: @sammosummo One of the main principles in programming (and OOP especially) is the concept of *separation of concerns*. That is not only important conceptually, but also practically, whenever the language follows that pattern. With all due respect, what you "believe" is irrelevant: using a timer for that purpose is conceptually inconsistent, and even if it was valid, that doesn't prevent you to, at least, *try* the other approach. As said above, using a timer for that is nonsensical if done in the main thread: that's *not* its intended purpose, and it's conceptually wrong too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be cautious about using a `QTimer` with a zero interval. If you don't call a waiting function in the signal handler, it will result in a high CPU usage due to a busy loop. (It can be nearly 100%.)

In MacOS, you can see that by calling the `app.exec()` without calling the `main_window.timer.stop()`.

And why does the `QTest.qWait()` not result in a high CPU usage on MacOS? The [`QTest::qWait()`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/v6.5.0/src/corelib/kernel/qtestsupport_core.cpp#L85) calls the [`QCoreApplication::processEvents()`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/v6.5.0/src/corelib/kernel/qcoreapplication.cpp#L1381), which runs a loop calling the [`QEventDispatcherCoreFoundation::processEvents()`](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/v6.5.0/src/corelib/kernel/qeventdispatcher_cf.mm#L328), which calls `CFRunLoopRunInMode()` one more time and returns `false`. So, the `QTest.qWait()` will call the `QTestPrivate::qSleep()` less frequently if you update the UI in the signal handler. (Updating the UI may cause new events are enqueued into the event queue.)

I think this behavior in MacOS is a side effect. What about reporting this [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/projects/QTBUG/issues)?